# Count not empty cells in datagrid C#

Tags: c#, count, datagridview, row, cell

I have one qwestion. How do i Count not empty cells in datagridview, and everytime I run this part of code, it got to count + SPECIFIC n NUMBER of not empty cells.
I mean ... for example, I have 100 rows, this rows will fill when program is start, row by row, I need to do something at not empty cell in row number ( SPECIFIC n NUMBER ) 25 ( it will stop fill rows proccess ), after I run again this part of code, it must do something in row 50 ( +25 ), and so on, every 25 rows. Here is my part of code.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < dataMailist.RowCount; j++)
{
    if (dataMailist.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value != null) counter++;

}

if (counter == HERE THE SPECIFIC n NUMBER)
{
    buttonStart.Enabled = false;
    dataMailist.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "Limit";
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Or just ignore already filled cells and count rows by not empty cell when program runs again.

Comment: I am not clear about what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain a bit more? If you can throw in an example that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is simply to step from 25 units use modulo.
counter % 25 = reminder of counter/25 = 0 each time counter is a multiple of 25.

```
//declare as global
int counter = 0;

{.....}

for (int j = 0; j < dataMailist.RowCount; j++)
{
    if (dataMailist.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value != null) counter++;

}

if (counter % 25 == 0) //modulo 
{
    buttonStart.Enabled = false;
    dataMailist.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "Limit";
    cts.Cancel();
}
```